# Plot math function f(x) with varying values of x and for different values of n

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, math, plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for i in range(0,100,10):
    function = (1/2) + (2/3.14) * (sin(2*(i)+1)x)/(2*(i)+1)
plt.plot(function)
```

I have a function `:fN(x) = (1/2) + (2/pi) * (sin[(2n+1)x])/(2n+1)` and I need to plot it for values of

```
n= 0, 10 ,20,...., 100.
```

Please help, I have not used python for a long time.
thank you.

.

Comment: Indent your code

Comment: Where is `x` defined???

Comment: some arbitrary variable like in sin(x) it can go from 0 to infinity

Comment: So do you want multiple graphs?

Comment: a single graph for all n from 0 to 100 by 10 increments

Comment: So do you mean that `x` is a previously defined float value and you want to hold that value constant while varying `n` over the graph from `0` to `100` by `10`s? And is `100` to be included in the graph (in your current code it is not included)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `x` to be previously defined as a float value. You also need to import the `sin()` function, correct the syntax in your expression (you need a multiply symbol in front of the `x`), and define `function` so it is a list or similar data type. I also changed your `range` expression so `100` is included in your values for `n` and removed the redundant import of `pyplot`.

The code below should do what you want.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import sin


x = 1

function = [(1/2) + (2/3.14) * (sin(2*i+1) * x) / (2*i+1)
    for i in range(0, 101, 10)]
plt.plot(function)
```

The resulting graph, for `x=1`, is

[image]

A little more work is needed if you want the values of `n` to be noted along the horizontal axis. As it is the numbers shown are the indices of the values in the `function` list. To show those values of `n` replace the last line of my code with

```
ivals = list(range(0, 101, 10))
plt.plot(ivals, function)
```

then you get this graph:

[image]